# Add two columns to a pandas DataFrame based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to add two new columns with different values based on two conditions.

Source **sample data** for left and right DataFrames

| id | rec_type | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13759 | U | 20210113 |
| 23806 | N | NaN |
| 21347 | U | 20210113 |
| 36904 | N | NaN |

| id |
| --- |
| 23806 |
| 21347 |

Expected output:

| id | rec_type | end_date | _merge | error_code | error_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13759 | U | 20210113 | left_only | 601 | update record not available in right table |
| 23806 | N | NaN | both | 0 | 0 |
| 21347 | U | 20210113 | both | 0 | 0 |
| 36904 | N | NaN | left_only | 602 | New record not available in right table |

I am using numpy (np) select to achieve my requirement as in below code but I am getting error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

merged_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df,
                     how='outer',
                     on=['id'],
                    indicator=True)

merged_df = merged_df.query('_merge != "right_only"')

conditions = [((merged_df['_merge'] == "left_only") &
               (merged_df['rec_type'] == "U") &
               (merged_df['end_date'].notnull())),
              ((merged_df['_merge'] == "left_only") &
               (merged_df['rec_type'] == "N") &
               (merged_df['end_date'].isnull()))]

error_codes = dict()
error_codes['error_code'] = [601, 602]
error_codes['error_description'] = ['update record not available in right table',
                                    'New record not available in right table']
                                      
merged_df['error_code'] = np.select(conditions, error_codes['error_code'])
merged_df['error_description'] = np.select(conditions, error_codes['error_description'])
```

I am getting below error, please share suggestions to resolve the error.

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> validate_df['error_code'] = np.select(conditions,
> error_codes['error_code'])
>
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> validate_df['error_description'] = np.select(conditions,
> error_codes['error_description'])

Thanks,

Raghunath.

**Note: Code is working fine with sample data but with more data, getting above error**

Comment: try to add .copy() : merged_df = merged_df.query('_merge != "right_only"').copy()

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by changing

```
merged_df = merged_df.query('_merge != "right_only"')
```

to below code

```
merged_df = merged_df[merged_df._merge != "right_only"]
```